# How big is the world in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm currently building a town in Minecraft Pocket Edition and I'm wondering how many blocks long and how many blocks wide the world is.

Comment: Your question is very vague. What platform are you looking for the dimensions of?

Comment: I just mean how long is it from side to side and is it an even square?

Comment: How long is what? What are you trying to build? If you're just trying to build a house, it doesn't matter what the dimensions are so long as you like it. If you're trying to build a particular thing, you're going to have to be more specific than "the platform".

Comment: When you say "the platform" do you mean the size of the actual entire world?  (If so, I'm guessing you don't speak English natively...calling this 'the platform' is very confusing)

Comment: yes I mean the entire world what are the dimensions

Answer (score 10):

This question is quite vague, however I believe that you are asking what size the entire world is in Minecraft pocket edition.

According to [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition#Gameplay):

> The Pocket Edition world is 255x255 blocks.

Please note that as of version 0.9.0, the world is infinite.

Comment: thanks so much in pockey edition i'm build a 255x255 floor above the world t build a town on and I wanted the center to be marked

Comment: Not a problem, please mark the ticket answer as accepted so its not listed as open. Hopefully this will help others wondering aswell. Thanks :)

Comment: Strange, I thought it would be doubled numbers, like this, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, **256**

Comment: Also, this information is outdated as of the recent 0.9.0 update.

Answer (score 5):

As of the 0.9.0 update, worlds are infinite. This means that the farther you walk out, the more chunks you load. Unfortunately, there is a "limit" of sorts. This is called the [farlands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Farlands). After traveling out 12,550,745 blocks, you'll be at the very edge of the farlands. It's rather unlikely you'll ever reach that point though, due to these factors.

> - Gaps between chunks at about 100,000 blocks out.

> - Jitteriness in player movement at about 700,000 blocks out.

> - The world crashes regularly and is completely unplayable at about 900,000 blocks out.

If you go **truly** quite a distance to 32,000,000 blocks out, you'll encounter what Tommasso Checchi has dubbed, the Stripe Lands. Blocks past this point are "fake" and you can fall right through them.

If you choose to make an "old", or limited size world, the world size is `x1000 y128 s1000`.

---

## Farlands

[image]

---

## Stripe lands

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The height is set at 64 blocks high.

Comment: The asker only needed the height and width.

Answer (score 1):

The Old world type is very small and contains just a few biomes, while the Infinite world type, like its name says, is somehow infinite, because of the Far Lands still existing. According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/minecraft_pe), the Far Lands have the classic format in the north and just an ocean in the south. I am sure that the Infinite world is infinite from north to south,but I am not sure if it's the same from west to east. The height limit is just below the clouds.

Answer (score -1):

Its 246 by 246 blocks I count it. 0.5.0

Answer (score -2):

In version 0.3.3 Alpha it is 266x266

Comment: Source?  This doesn't sound plausible, due it not being a binary multiplier.

Comment: @fbueckert It's definitely plausible, but pretty unlikely.  More likely would be that the above is a typo, and Matt meant 255x255.