# What are the limits of Minecraft worlds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Although Minecraft uses its peculiar cube art for all its elements, it respects some physics laws in some manner.

If Minecraft uses gravity laws and we expect it to respect computer memory limits, the worlds created in the game would be spheres, or cubes because of the art design.

So, how large is the radius of that sphere (or the "side length of the cube" ) in these worlds? Is it the same as the Earth or infinite?

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72763/how-big-is-the-world-in-minecraft-pocket-edition).

Comment: Minecraft is a Flat Earther's dream.

Comment: *If Minecraft uses gravity laws* - quite a big "if" - it's unlikely they've implemented *general relativity* to simulate the gravity between celestial bodies!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean how big is a Minecraft world, [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Overworld#Limitations) has the answer:

> In Java Edition, the map contains a world border located by default at X/Z coordinates ±29,999,984. The world border is an animated wall of blue stripes. Standing near the border results in a red vignette appearing around the screen. Most entities are unable to pass the border.

> In Bedrock Edition, Infinite-type worlds have no fixed horizontal limits, but either generation stops or normal game behavior begins to break down at extreme distances; the exact details depend on the platform. However, experiments suggest that players can generally reach at least X/Z ±30,000,000 before such problems occur.

Comment: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/World_boundary has more info about hte various limits, quirks, and effects, and history. https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Java_Edition_Distance_Effects is a related and cool read.

Comment: @MooingDuck keep in mind that Minecraft wiki is moving from fandom to minecraft.wiki, so it's better to use that source for your links

Comment: https://minecraft.wiki/w/World_boundary and https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_distance_effects and https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_distance_effects and https://minecraft.wiki/w/Far_Lands then

Comment: Well, it represents a radius of approximately 9.549km, kkkk

Comment: It is about 1,5x the Earth radius

Comment: @kokbira it's not a sphere, it's a square

Comment: Ach so. We know about the art design ;) But, is it a sphere inscribed in a cube or a cube circumscribed in a sphere? Kkkkk

Comment: @kokbira: It is not a sphere of any kind. It is a flat plane.

Comment: It's not a flat plane, it's a rectangular prism.